# Dialogflow - Hangouts Chat payload example

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, fulfillment

Does anybody have a custom payload example for Google Hangouts Chat message?
I'm trying this but no message is displayed:

```js
agent.add(new Payload('hangouts', hangoutsMessage, {sendAsMessage: true}));
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Double check your `dialogflow-fulfillment` version in your `package.json` if you're using the inline editor in dialogflow. By default, it's set to `0.5.0` so you need to update it.

In package.json:
`"dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.5.0"` --> `"dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.6.1"`

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Sending cards or images on Hangouts chat via fulfillment is not working at the moment. Currently you can only send cards, buttons and images on Hangouts via Intent rich messages.</strike>

Confirming havokles's answer, Payload, Cards and Images via fulfillment are currently woking on hangouts by updating your package.json's `"dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.5.0" to "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.6.1"`.